# Riemannian distance via the length of a curve

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, arc-length, variational-analysis

I am reading a book where they define the Riemannian distance between two points on a manifold. Naturally it is given as the infimum of the integral of the length of the curves which connect the two points:

[image]

However, then they make a reparameterization of the curve, and suddenly the distance and the `norm' inside the integral gets squared. How does this happen? And also is the change of variables in the reparameterisation $s=\frac{t-a}{b-a}$?

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: @rych Figalli's book on optimal transport.

Answer (score 2):

There's an application of Jensen's inequality happening here, which is why the *unit* interval is used in the second definition.

The goal is to show that the two definitions of distance coincide. The integrals appearing in the first equation are reparameterization-invariant, so the first infimum can be taken to be over curves of constant speed on the unit interval. For such curves, $(\int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)| dt)^2 = \int_0^1|\gamma'(t)|^2 dt$, so that the second definition of distance is no larger than the first. For the other inequality, Jensen's inequality shows that for any curve $\gamma: [0,1] \to M$ with $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$, $$\int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)|^2 dt \geq \left( \int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)| dt \right)^2, $$ so that the two definitions of distance are the same.